# How to disable the home indicator of iOS in Expo?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am using expo SDK 46. I would like to make the home indicator inactive or hide it. In my case, just one gesture movement closes the application. I want to make it harder for users since they can accidentally send the app to the background. As far as I see, we need two separate gesture movements to send the game to the background. An example game is Pokemon Unite. So, it should be possible.

I am already using `expo-status-bar` to hide the Status bar, and it seems it is not affecting the home indicator.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Navigation rod]

Comment: I'm also looking for this but as some background, here's a comment in the GitHub repo asking for the same

Comment: I think you forgot the link :)

Comment: woops: https://github.com/expo/expo/discussions/14286#discussioncomment-1686869

Answer (score 4):

Version 6.X of React Navigation have `auto hide home indicator` option now

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#autohidehomeindicator
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10651

Example

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="XXXMenu" 
    screenOptions={{ autoHideHomeIndicator: true }}>
<Stack.Navigator>
```

Making the home indicator visible again is still easy despite the config, but it hides the indicator for non-active screens.

Comment: I tried this but the home indicator still shows. is there something else I should do?

Comment: I am still looking for a more comprehensive solution, no luck so far @ItayLador